# Recommended PhpStorm configuration for Shopware?

Tags: javascript, configuration, phpstorm, shopware, shopware6

I have noticed the JavaScript classes not resolving when typing the following in a Shopware JavaScript plugin:

[image]

This got me thinking. Is there any way to solve this not resolving? Are there any other configuration recommendations for Shopware development in PhpStorm? I've already seen some in the Shopware Academy backend course and the documentation, but might there be more?

Answer (score 2):

#### Updated answer, quick solution

In your project directory tree find `src/Storefront/Resources/app/storefront`, right click the folder, `Mark directory as`, `Resource Root`. This should make the aliased modules resolved.

[image]

#### Older answer, possible permanent fix

Theoretically PhpStorm should be able to resolve the aliases defined in `src/Storefront/Resources/app/storefront/webpack.config.js`.

However it fails analyzing that file:

```
Webpack
Can't analyze webpack.config.js: coding assistance will ignore module resolution rules in this file.
Possible reasons: this file is not a valid webpack configuration file or its format is not currently supported by the IDE.
Error details:  Definition file does not exists
```

I found the reason is line 465 of `src/Storefront/Resources/app/storefront/webpack.config.js`:

```js
const injector = new WebpackPluginInjector('var/plugins.json', webpackConfig, 'storefront');
```

Replacing that line with the following line made the modules using the aliases resolvable:

```js
const injector = new WebpackPluginInjector(path.resolve(projectRootPath, 'var/plugins.json'), webpackConfig, 'storefront');
```

If you're using the development template and the Shopware mono-repo is located in the `platform` diretory this change will make Webpack look for `platform/var/plugins.json` instead. So either copy or symlink `var/plugins.json` to that location.

This is obviously just a temporary workaround and needs to properly be fixed eventually.

As a side note: The separate `webpack.config.js` for the `administration` also fails to be analyzed by PhpStorm as of now. So this won't fix non-resolvable aliases for PhpStorm in the administration.